# url that includes parameters and redirection to https

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, https

I have problems figuring out how to redirect from http to https (with rewrite rules) for only selected urls that include paramaters.

For example... http://www.site.com/?action=login should redirect to https://www.site.com/?action=login

Tried few standard redirection syntaxes found online but couldn't manage adjust it to work with such parameter included url

thanks

Comment: why don't you use, `header('Location: https://....');`? or is that out of picture?

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect all requests to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This will specify somewhat more, based on query string contents:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^action=(login|foo|bar)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

You might need to alter `[R,L]` to `[R,L,QSA]` (QueryStringAppend), can't test now.